# regular expression that will find: F.01, F1.01, F9.99, F10.01,

Tags: regex, notepad++

I need a regular expression that will find:
F.01,
F1.01,
F9.99,
F10.01,
And any decimal to the second place in between.

Comment: On which platform will you use?

Comment: Currently I am using notepad++

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this pattern
`F\d+\.\d\d$`
for most of the platforms it should work

Comment: more specifically I need it to find any one or two digit number to the first or second decimal place lower than a manually changing number.

Comment: e.g. F.1,  F.11, F1.1, F1.11

Comment: @Morfyus well, did you be able to try?

Comment: Yes I tried it and it finds F10.99, but not F3.4 for example.

Comment: The end result I'm trying to achieve is to quickly find F lower than say F5. to F99.99 and replace. The initial output will vary from F.01 to F99.99 with none to two decimal places.

Comment: Did you see my previous comment? I just edited it to be more specific. I use https://regexr.com/ to test expressions.

Comment: If I simply edit your suggested pattern, and use it as a three step, then it becomes a proficient enough solution. I thank you!

Comment: For anyone who may read this again I found a simple regular expression that finds what I was looking for as follows           '''F[0-9]?(\.[0-9]?[0-9]?)'''